# AWS S3 .Net List Objects 3rd level only

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to list objects from my S3 bucket, 3rd level of a certain folder only:

```
bucket
   samples
      XXXX
        XXXX_XXXXX
        XXXX_XXXXX
      YYYY
        YYYY_YYYYY
        YYYY_YYYYY
```

The XXXX_XXXXX and YYYY_YYYYY folders only.

Using C#, this is my code:

```
 using (IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client("awsAccessKeyId", "awsSecretAccessKey", RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("eu-central-1")))
            {
                ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Prefix = "samples/",
                    Delimiter = "/"
                };
                do
                {
                    ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request);

                    if (response.S3Objects.Count() > 0)
                    { // CODE }
```

The response.S3Objects is empty. If I remove the Delimiter from the Request ALL the objects are returned, and the loading time is too long.
I've been following the AWS S3 [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html), but it simply returns nothing. Please help me understand what is wrong. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be looking in [`CommonPrefixes`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/P_Amazon_S3_Model_ListObjectsResponse_CommonPrefixes.htm), not `S3Objects`.  `CommonPrefixes` gives you all of the prefixes up to the *next* delimiter, each of which you use to repeat the request, taking you another level deeper each time.